# Attchment on Opportunity in Batch apex

Tags: batch, attachment

I have a requirement of creating an excel or pdf from batch apex.
I insert few records in batch on some business logic. There are few records which i skip from creation if the logic is not satisfied.
So the requirement is, i have to create an attachment excel or pdf of the skipped records and attach it to opportunity from batch apex.

Is this a feasible solution and can we achieve this using batch apex.
Need help with this solution..

Comment: Your question is asking for other people to write code for you. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions that are real problems or errors with our code. Posting requests to write code for you will get closed. If you need assistance learning the Salesforce technical environment, I recommend you look at the many workbooks available from Developer Documentation and also begin the learning path at Trailhead.

Comment: Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you.